# File is returned by reasteasy with additional bytes

Tags: javascript, java, rest, binary, resteasy

I'm trying to return a binary file as a response on HTTP POST request. 
My API looks like this:

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
 @POST
 @Path("/{param}/path")
 public @NotNull Response exportPlayer(@NotNull @PathParam("param") Param param,
                                       @Nullable @FormParam("formParam") Param2 param2) {
 final byte[] resultFileContent = getResultContent(); //returns some binary serialized information

 return Response.ok(resultFileContent ).header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = myfile").build();
}
```

In this byte array first four bytes is an integer indicating the size of the following content, like this:

```
**00 00 00 F0** 31 33 35 34 30 38 34 3B 36 36 3B 5C
4E 3B 5C 4E 3B 32 30 32 30 2D 30 33 2D 31 30 20
...
```

Here 00 00 00 F0 means that the following content block contains 240 bytes, and the rest bytes is content itself
This file is returned correctly when using curl

```
>curl --user user:password -X POST --data "formParam=value" "http://127.0.0.1:8085/rest/api/param/export" > testExport.bin
```

The problem occurs when I call thi API via browser in my web client. It starts to return some extra bytes at the beginning of the file:

```
**00 00 00 EF BF BD** 31 33 35 34 30 38 34 3B 36 36 
3B 5C 4E 3B 5C 4E 3B 32 30 32 30 2D 30 33 2D 31
```

the content is the same, but first two bytes seem to be corrupted. 
Here's the way I download the file:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: /*my url*/,
      data: data
      method: "POST",
      error: /*some handler*/,
      success: answer => {
                const link = $('<a>', {
                    href: 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(answer),
                    download: "player_" + playerId
                }).css('display', 'none')
                    .appendTo('body');
                link.get(0).click();
                link.remove();
             }
    });
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a workaround, but the issue is still unsolved.
I changed my API to @GET and queried it with

[HTML]

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/rest/api/$param/method" method="get" id="my_form">
```

[JS]

```
$("#export_player_form").submit()
```